# Hypothetical question regarding 2D eye rigging for unity/mocap

Tags: texturing, uv, export, unity, motion-capture

I just recently modeled a character with 2d Eyes. The eyes are flat planes that rest on the surface of the face via applied shrink-wrap mod. The eyes have a texture of the pupils and the pupils move by using UV Warp and a single bone. [(Tutorial Video Here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk)

[image]

Now, it's clear to me that this method of eye animation is purely for animation and not really adequate for exporting to use in things like video games or motion tracking software.

*So here's my hypothetical:* how can I do 2D eye movement on the surface of a mesh?

I've been using blender on and off for about a year and this is my first time trying to import a model to Unity and possibly use the model in motion tracking software like VseeFace or VRchat. I'm looking for solutions to this issue so my characters can have completely flat cartoon eyes. And I'd like to export as an .fbx if possible.

I'd like to hear some opinions on the options I came up with.

- **Option 1** Do the work in Unity instead of Blender. I don't actually know if UV warp would transfer to .fbx. I'm pretty sure when exporting to .fbx you can choose to apply modifiers but then that sets them where they are permanently doesn't it? I am sure that in Unity it could be programmed where a mesh constantly moves along the coordinates of a texture to simulate eye movement. But in the event I upload the model to VseeFace or some other motion tracking software, I'm not sure if anything I program in Unity would transfer over.
- **Option 2** Leave eye mesh completely white and create a second mesh for the pupil on top. Then use bones to move that pupil along the surface of the white sclera mesh. This option seems more do-able but I'm not sure how I would go about it. Would I add shape keys in up, down, left, and right positions and then export those in leu of constraints? Does VseeFace have its own constraint system so I don't have to worry about it? But again, the pupil needs to be flush with the sclera at all times and not leave the sclera. The sclera mesh is shrink-wrapped to the front of the head, so it's not flat. Would the shape keys abide by the shrink-wrap even if the modifier was no longer in tact in the .fbx file?

Comment: Yes, those are basically your options.  Option 2 can use shapekeys (for flat eyes) or skeletal animation.  Flush is easy, provided that the surface of the eye is a portion of a sphere, or else a plane.  Option 1 wouldn't be export a UV warp, which won't happen; it would be create a UV warp in Unity, probably in the shader, which is just about the easiest shader work you could ever do.

Comment: thank you! for option 2 the surface of the eye (sclera) is a subdivided square plane. it's got an applied shrink-wrap mod on it to make it flush with the surface of the face, so it's neither a perfect sphere section nor a completely flat plane. But, I'm thinking that if i do the shape keys of the pupil before applying the shrinkwrap mod then they should move along the surface of the eye just fine? UV warp in unity for option 1 sounds like a simple and fun project. but if I uploaded to vr chat I assume I would lose that data? would shape keying be the better option for eye-tracking software?

Comment: No, it doesn't work to do shapekey and then apply the shrinkwrap.  Don't know anything about VR chat.

Comment: well thanks anyway, dude! at the very least this has helped me reduced the amount of time i'd be spending just doing this via trial and error.